# Changing a label's foreground color using style triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I created a style for a Label which is supposed to change the color of the foreground depending on the value of the "IsEnabled" property:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledToggleTextBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
   (...)
</Style>
```

One of my controls has a label with this style applied. The "IsEnabled" property of the label is bound to a property in the control's View-Model:

View's XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="RememberCredentialsLabel" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleLabelStyle}" IsEnabled="{Binding SaveCredentials}" Content="Remember Credentials" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,28.849,39.339,10.124" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="130.5" Foreground="White"/>
```

View-Model Property:

```
public bool SaveCredentials
{
    get
    {
        return _saveCredentials;
    }
    set
    {
        _saveCredentials = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SaveCredentials);
    }
}
```

The property is properly bound, and the control is alerted when its value changes. The problem is, the color of the label's foreground never changes. I tried hard-coding a value for the Foreground in the style (ex: Red), but it still doesn't change.

As a last resort, I tried changing the visibility status of the control to Hidden instead of changing the foreground's value and it worked. The label would hide and display itself accordingly.

Why am I unable to change the value of the foreground from within a trigger in a style ?

I'm using Expression Blend 4 as well as editing the code manually. I'm also using PRISM 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not set the `Forground` on the `Label` itself, the **local value** will override the **style trigger** due to [**precedence**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The trigger thus does not affect the `Foreground`.

Setters can be overriden by triggers though, so you could move the value into a style setter.

Comment: Astounding reply, thank you. I learn something new everyday, I love this site and my field :). Thanks again !

Comment: @HusseinKhalil: Just `Setters` in a `Style`, like `<Style><Setter Property="..." Value="..."/></Style>`, setters can also appear in triggers (like in your style).

Comment: @H.B: Yep thank you, just figured it out also thanks to Tigran's reply. It all made sense :)

Comment: @HusseinKhalil: This by the way is one of the most common things people stumble over in WPF, it happens so easily and it is not exactly intuitive.  Happended to me as well in fact.

Comment: @H.B: Tell me about it, I would have spent the afternoon trying to figure it out. Glad I'm not the only one making this mistake ! Consider it a lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Just guess:

*To me* is seems that in `Label` definition `Foreground="White"` should be removed, as it overcome the style definition. Instead this add

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
   </Trigger>
```

*Should* work...

Comment: Thanks Tigran, much appreciated ! You and H.B nailed it.